# Power Automate get approver Responses before timeout

Tags: power-automate

I need to collect Responses from a Power Automate *Start and wait for an approval* action before timeout. In an approval flow a very usual scenario is that not every approver responds, which means that an *Everyone must approve* or *Wait for all responses* action cannot complete. In this scenario, is there some way to get all submitted Responses e.g. after 7 days? If *Start and wait for an approval* times out it becomes impossible to get Responses (without going to Dataverse, which I do no thave access to).

I envisage a flow something like below, but of course Delay will not trigger until *Start and wait for an approval* completes/times out.

Have seen [this helpful input](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/300523/get-outcome-of-the-start-and-wait-for-approval-vs-get-the-responsescomments-f) but do not have enough SharePoint points to ask directly there :(

[image: envisaged flow]